# spring-security-saml2-service-provider 5.6.9: 404 Errors for SP Metadata and IDP Initiated Login

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, saml

I'm currently upgrading an existing application from **`spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.10.RELEASE`** (which has reached end-of-life) to **`spring-security-saml2-service-provider 5.6.9`**. As these versions have significant differences, I started by creating a sample Spring application based on the example provided at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/scndr/medium-blog-digital-software-architecture/tree/main/spring-boot-spring-security-saml2). This test application worked correctly, allowing both IDP-initiated logins and the successful download of SP metadata using the URL **`http://{host-name}/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registration-id}`**.

However, after integrating similar changes into my actual project, I'm encountering issues. Here's a brief overview of what I did:

1. **Code Addition:** I wrote a class (similar to the one in the sample application) in my codebase.

   ```
   // Necessary Imports

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       private ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();


       @Autowired(required = false)
       private RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

           LOG.info("In the configure method");
           if (isSAMLEnabled()) {
               LOG.info("Inside IF");
               http
                       .authorizeRequests()
                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
                       .and()
                       .saml2Login(); 

               Converter<HttpServletRequest, RelyingPartyRegistration> relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
               Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
               http.addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
           }


           LOG.info("Configure method done.");
       }

       @Bean
       public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {

           LOG.info("Inside the bean method");
           if (isSAMLEnabled()) {
               return createRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository();
           } else {
               return null;
           }
       }

       private RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository createRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {

           LOG.info("Inside Repo method");


           String entityId = //Appropriate Value
           String ssoUrl = //Appropriate Value
           String certificatePath = //Appropriate Value

           try {
               Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(certificatePath);
               InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
               CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
               X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inputStream);
               Saml2X509Credential credential = Saml2X509Credential.verification(certificate);

               RelyingPartyRegistration relyingPartyRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistration
                       .withRegistrationId("okta-idp")
                       .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party
                               .entityId(entityId)
                               .singleSignOnServiceLocation(ssoUrl)
                               .wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false)
                               .verificationX509Credentials(c -> c.add(credential))
                       ).build();

               LOG.info("repo method successful");
               return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistration);

           } catch (Exception e) {
               LOG.info("Failed in repo method");
               throw new RuntimeException("Error configuring SAML ", e);
           }
       }

       private boolean isSAMLEnabled() {
           LOG.info("Checking if SAML is enabled...");
           // Logic to check if SAML is enabled, this part works fine.
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Observation in Logs:** Upon restarting my server, the logs indicate that the **`relyingParty`** instance is being set up correctly.

   ```
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,200 INFO Inside the bean method
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,200 INFO Checking if SAML is enabled...
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,200 INFO Inside Repo method
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,212 INFO repo method successful
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,324 INFO In the configure method
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,324 INFO Checking if SAML is enabled...
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,324 INFO Inside IF
   2024-01-29 11:36:08,980 INFO Configure method done.
   ```
3. **Issue Encountered:** Despite the logs suggesting correct setup, accessing **`http://{host-name}/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registration-id}`** results in a 404 Error. Similarly, I'm also receiving a 404 Error when attempting an IDP-initiated login.

   ```
   HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
   URI: /saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registartion-id}
   STATUS:  404
   MESSAGE: Not Found
   SERVLET: default
   ```

I am puzzled as to what could be causing these issues. It seems like my setup should work as it's based on a working example. Has anyone faced similar problems when upgrading to **`spring-security-saml2-service-provider 5.6.9`**? Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or what I should check?